# DSpace migration from 1.8.x to 6.x

Tags: data-migration, dspace

I am in need of migrating from DSpace 1.8.2 to 6. I have installed the new DSpace in CentOS7 server with PostgreSQL 9.5. Now I want to get all the data from old repository to new repository.

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Take a look at the packager command for DSpace.  This will allow you to export metadata and bitstreams in to AIP packages that can be ingested into your new repository.  https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC6x/Importing+and+Exporting+Content+via+Packages

Comment: Thank you @terrywb. I'll have a look.